Add new rows in a tibble based on a fixed value range
I want to add new rows for each ID (1,2,3) between a fixed range of values (Year: 2006-2010), while keeping the preexisting data (Size column). Here is an example:
tibble::tribble(
  ~Year, ~ID, ~Size,
  2006,   1,  5,
  2007,   1,  8,
  2009,  2,  6,
  2010,   2,  4, 
  2007,   3,  1,
  2009, 3, 2
)

What I want is something like this:
tibble::tribble(
  ~Year, ~ID, ~Size,
  2006,   1,  5,
  2007,   1,  8,
  **2008, 1, NA,
  2009, 1, NA,
  2010, 1, NA,
  2006, 2, NA,
  2007, 2, NA,
  2008, 2, NA,**
  2009,  2,  6,
  2010,   2,  4, 
  **2006, 3, NA,**
  2007,   3,  1,
  **2008, 3, NA,**
  2009, 3, 2,
 ** 2010, 3, NA**
)

I tried with loops and add_rows but I was not successful.

Since you're using tribble I assume you're happy with a tidyverse solution:
df2 <- df1 |> complete(Year = min(Year):max(Year), ID) |> arrange(ID, Year)
df2

gives:
# A tibble: 15 × 3
    Year    ID  Size
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2006     1     5
 2  2007     1     8
 3  2008     1    NA
 4  2009     1    NA
 5  2010     1    NA
 6  2006     2    NA
 7  2007     2    NA
 8  2008     2    NA
 9  2009     2     6
10  2010     2     4
11  2006     3    NA
12  2007     3     1
13  2008     3    NA
14  2009     3     2
15  2010     3    NA

